# Best language/method to produce a dynamic user-customisable xml-based GUI?

Tags: user-interface

I'm looking to start a personal project - but have no idea where to start!

Take a look at the [igoogle website](http://www.google.com/ig). 
Basically it's comprised of multiple columns of different sized boxes, that can be easily moved around by the user.

I'm looking for the best/easiest way to create something like that, where the data displayed in the boxes is populated via XML.

Suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

JQueryUI Seems to be the best way to go about it.
The following URLs provide examples of how it's supposed to work, and code to do it.

(:// removed to stop URL's being filtered)

http jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets
http jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/
http jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/inettuts/
http www.webappers.com/2008/11/19/how-to-create-igoogle-interface-with-jquery/
http geekswithblogs.net/AzamSharp/archive/2008/02/21/119882.aspx
http www.shopdev.co.uk/blog/cookies-with-jquery-designing-collapsible-layouts/

If you want to do it with in .NET using WPF:
http blacklight.codeplex.com/
http mightymeaty.members.winisp.net/blacklight.silverlight/